# How to write Union All query in Query DSL

Tags: querydsl

Need to implement sql query like:

```
SELECT A.class, A.section 
FROM 
STUDENT A 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT on A.student_id = B.id 
WHERE DEPT_NBR is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT A.class, A.section 
FROM 
TEACHER A 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT on A.teacher_id = B.id 
WHERE DEPT_NBR is not null
```

How can I write such statement with QueryDSL ? ( I am not using any JPA). Any help/hint is much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

There are many examples that can help you.

```
public void union_multiple_columns() throws SQLException {
        SubQueryExpression<Tuple> sq1 = query().from(employee).select(employee.firstname, employee.lastname);
        SubQueryExpression<Tuple> sq2 = query().from(employee).select(employee.lastname, employee.firstname);
        List<Tuple> list = query().union(sq1, sq2).fetch();
        assertFalse(list.isEmpty());
        for (Tuple row : list) {
            assertNotNull(row.get(0, Object.class));
            assertNotNull(row.get(1, Object.class));
        }
    }
```

This example was taken from the project itself:
https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/blob/8f96f416270d0353f90a6551547906f3c217833a/querydsl-sql/src/test/java/com/querydsl/sql/UnionBase.java#L73

Comment: query() comes from AbstractBaseClass and returns TestQuery.  So, what do I replace query() with?

Comment: var queryFactory = new SQLQueryFactory(...); queryFactory.query().union(SQLExpressions.select(...).from(...).where(...), SQLExpressions.select(...).from(...).where(....)).fetch()

Comment: I was trying to use JPAQueryFactory.  I didn't realize it was SQLQueryFactory.  What are the Maven coordinates for SQLQueryFactory?

Comment: The original question was about querydsl-sql and not JPA. You can find SQLQueryFactore in "com.querydsl:querydsl-sql:5.0.0".

Answer (score 7):

so that others won't search for that too much... [JPA doesn't support unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958614/union-to-jpa-query), hence querydsl when running on top of JPA doesn't support unions. It does support them when running on top of raw SQL though, see natros's answer for that.