# ORDER BY JPA QUERY

Tags: sql, jpa

What is the correct JPA syntax when using union and order by?

At the moment I have something in the following manner:

```
SELECT st FROM Student st JOIN TREAT (st.type as HighShcool) hs
UNION
Select st FROM Student st JOIN TREAT (st.type as MiddleShcool) ms
ORDER BY st.id
```

This is failing and the exception that I am getting is the end of the query is wrong i.e `ORDER BY section`. Without this, it is working.

Please help, I have no idea why it is happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UNION to JPA Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958614/union-to-jpa-query)

Comment: No, I have looked at this, the issue stems directly from JPA. Theortcally, when you create a query from the entity manager you would not be able to put a UNION into the request JPA content. But you can use StringBuilder to circumvent this and toString() it in. But it does not accept the ORDER BY.