# Min and Max from same subquery

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

If a query having a subselect for the highest money payed and the lowest money payed in example:

```
SELECT p.firstname, 
       p.lastname, 
       (SELECT MAX(pmt.amount) 
          FROM Payment pmt 
         WHERE pmt.person.id = p.id)  maxAmount,
       (SELECT MIN(pmt.amount) 
          FROM Payment pmt 
         WHERE pmt.person.id = p.id)  minAmount,
  FROM Person p
```

We need to write two subqueries. This have a bad performance on huge databases.

Any solutions in plain JPQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UNION to JPA Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958614/union-to-jpa-query)

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri No. Union will create two result-rows. I need one result-row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:

```
   SELECT p.firstname,
          p.lastname, 
          MAX(pmt.amount),
          MIN(pmt.amount)
     FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN p.payments pmt
    GROUP BY p.firstname, p.lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge database this problem probably should be addressed by tweaking the schema design. Most RDBMS would have to do a full table scan on `Payment` table to find both minimum and maximum  `amount` value. You can check this by looking at [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-explain.html) output for your current query.

Since you are concerned with the query speed you can denormalize the schema and store the `maxAmount` and `minAmount` columns in `Person` table or create a new `PersonMinMaxPayment` table. You can then update these when new row is inserted into `Payment` table e.g. by declaring `@PrePersist` or [creating a trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtrigger.html).

There are also few more possibilities if your system can be eventually consistent. You can recalculate these values with a delay e.g. as a once a day batch job.

Comment: Sorry, plain JPQL only.

Comment: @Grim Let me know if you figure it out!

Comment: I think about a view, mapped as a readonly-class.

Comment: @Grim view is not a a JPQL solution

Comment: Yea, thats why I can not used it either. :)

Comment: Another approach is `concat(min(x),' to ',max(x))` in jpql. but this will generate one field instead of two.

Comment: @Grim you might want to check if the performance of the query would be any different with `concat()` approach. My guess no, but I don't know your database.

Comment: Postgres, its much faster using concat.

Comment: @Grim Nice. Any chance you can show the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output for the first query and then for the second query?