# How can I replace SQL query with UNION to receive same responce using JPA?

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've got some troubles to get distinct sender and receiver from database for my chat application:

This is my message model:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@NotNull
private String Content;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date date = new Date();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sender_id")
private User sender;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id")
private User receiver;
```

Assuming we are logged in as user A and there's database like this:

| sender | receiver |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | A |
| A | C |
| D | A |

The result I would like to achieve is:

B
C
D

Using SQL I can achieve this using this query:

```
select distinct receiver_id from message where sender_id =4 union 
select distinct sender_id from message as m where receiver_id = 4
```

But there is the problem, JPA does not support UNION :(

Send Help PLS

Comment: Well you could use a native query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thats true, but then resault would be just an Integer not an User object

Comment: JPA doesn't support union, but check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958614/union-to-jpa-query) for a workaround using a join.  Not sure how well it would perform.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Does not help at all

Comment: Note that the DISTINCT in your SQL query is useless as `UNION` will already remove duplicates

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh it's true, yesterday I didn't even notice.

Comment: Is the amount of data big enough to fordib you to do 2 queries and make the union in memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select either the `sender` or the `receiver` based on specification of a target value.  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-PqNk6R6))

```
select string_agg(res, ' ' order by res) 
  from ( 
        select distinct 
               case when sender = 'A'
                    then receiver 
                    else sender 
                end res
           from test
          where 'A'  in (sender, receiver)
      ) sq;
```

That is of course straight SQL. Unfortunately I do not know your obscurification manager (JPA?) so you will have to translate. Or just use raw SQL.