# EclipseLink UNION in FROM

Tags: eclipselink

I want to create a UNION in a FROM expression using EclipseLink. For simplicity I have an over-trivial example that actually can better be expressed by a WHERE clause.

```
select
  *
from 
  (
    select * from person where id < 10
    union
    select * from person where id > 20
  )
order by
  id
```

I know that JPA 2 does not support a UNION in a FROM clause. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18958802) EclipseLink supports UNION. And [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#UNION) are some examples how to do it in (extended) JPQL.

```
SELECT MAX(e.salary) FROM Employee e WHERE e.address.city = :city1
UNION SELECT MAX(e.salary) FROM Employee e WHERE e.address.city = :city2
```

Furthermore I found [some more examples](https://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/05/jpql-vs-sql-have-both-with-eclipselink.html) how to to mix standard JPA queries with EclipseLink extensions like `SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.lastName REGEXP '^Dr\.*'`. There is also an example how to mix Criteria API with these extensions.

```
JpaCriteriaBuilder cb = (JpaCriteriaBuilder)em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root emp = query.from(Employee.class);
query.where(cb.fromExpression(cb.toExpression(emp).get("firstName").regexp("^Dr\.*")));
```

Because of user specific ordering and filtering I need to create a dynamic query with an API rather than use some fixed JPQL.

I had a look into the `JpaCriteriaBuilder` class and find it hard to understand what exactly I can do with the few additional methods. While the above example seemed pretty comprehensible, I have no idea how to implement a more complex scenario like the UNION example at the beginning.

I am even not sure if such a statement is possible in the "mixing" of JPA Criteria API and EclipseLinks extensions. I also found an EclipseLink API with classes like `ReportQuery`, `JPAQueryBuilder` and `ExpressionBuilder`. I assume that I need to use these to implement the UNION statement. I struggle finding a decent documentation about this API or maybe some examples that go further than a `select * from person where name = 'mary'`.

Dose anyone know how to implement the above example in EclipseLink or can point me to a proper documentation?